# What are these components?

Tags: pcb, components

I'm trying to recreate parts of a rv control panel for replacing it with the raspberry pi, but I have a hard time figuring out what these parts are. the black one reads **"T8-2-472G"** and the red one **"L5|S332 817"** I guess they are some kind of multipack capacitors but I can't find anything about them. [image]

Comment: yeah, I didn't manage to get the components in focus with my phone ;-(

Comment: Well to be fair, Olin. (S)He did tell us the markings on the components. Picture quality can be improved, I agree. It is rather... insane (if that's the correct word) to be expect us interpret a blurry picture.

Answer (score 1):

The black one is a resistor packs.

I am not 100% sure how to interpret the code, but I guess the T8-2-472G is T8 for 8 pins, 2 for 4 independent resistors, 472 for 4700 Ohm (47 followed by two 0's). No clue wahat G is.

No idea what the other one is, it might be a resistor pack with a weird coding.

Answer (score 0):

### Voltage divider resistor [***SIP packs***](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b&biw=1233&bih=1187&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=8WTTWrmnIKLBjwT9xYaICQ&q=sip%20resistor%20pack&oq=sip%20resistor%20pack&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i24k1.68250.69438.0.97924.4.4.0.0.0.0.106.396.2j2.4.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.3.288...0i13k1j0i7i30k1j0i13i30k1j0i13i5i30k1.0.lYbiKaCtJa8) (single inline package)

A T8 should be a  double **T**erminated where the number of paired terminations is the number of pins minus 2 common pins on each end
similar to Bourns parts http://www.bourns.com/data/global/pdfs/dualterm.pdf

R values are given by the 3 digits with exponent.

G is a tolerance, as I recall F is 1%  with no suffix being looser.

These are known to perform better where ratios matter for gain or offset stability with better  matched ratios than discrete 1% parts inspite of absolute tolerances may be 1~10% . Some can be laser trimmed.

RED Resistor network
4610X-101-332LF Bourns
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, that will help me a lot and makes perfectly sense. You don't have an idea what the red one is, have you?